# How to color PCA results according to a factor?

Tags: r, pca

I am working with a dataset of multiple numerical variables (here called Env_) of which I have created a PCA. All these variables represent environmental factors. I further have a number of categorical variables representing biodiversity values (here called Biodiv_), linked to the environmental factors. I have turned the biodiversity value into a factor with 50 levels.

I want to create a PCA based on the environmental factors, which I have done. Next, I wish to color the individual datapoints according to my biodiversity variable in order to visually inspect where I find high and low levels of diversity. Basically, I want a plot similar to [the plot under segment 2 for Visualize PCA results](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/119-pca-in-r-using-ade4-quick-scripts/), but instead of coloring according to cos2, I want to color my points according to my biodiversity factor Biodiv_.

I am presently working with the ade4 and FactoMineR packages to create and visualize my PCA. I followed the overall guidelines of [FactoMineR](http://factominer.free.fr/factomethods/principal-components-analysis.html). I have also tried using the fviz_pca, with no better luck.

```
PCA1 <- PCA(complete[ ,1:9], 
        scale.unit = TRUE, graph = TRUE) 
##Provides a PCA plot with my 9 environmental variables

PCA2 <- PCA(complete, scale.unit = TRUE, 
        ncp = 5, quali.sup = c(10), graph = TRUE) 
##My attempt at adding the biodiversity factor to the plot. No change appear at my plot compared to the line above

plot.PCA(PCA2, axes = c(1,2), choix = "ind", habillage = 50) 
##I wish to color the points according to the biodiversity factor with 50 levels.
```

The following error occur:

```
Error in plot.PCA(complete_2PCA, axes = c(1, 2), choix = "ind", habillage = 50) : 
The variable 50 is not qualitative
```

An example of my data:

```
Env_1 Env_2   Env_3    Env_4   ... Env_9     Biodiv_10
14    78.9675 61.8300  5.4725  ... 4.947368  0.00
12    43.6950 14.8475  5.3775  ... 5.714286  0.12
15    56.1875 31.2800  6.1100  ... 5.200000  0.15
13    84.0100 68.7825  5.8500  ... 5.625000  0.88
24    63.4125 26.5525  5.5675  ... 5.363636  0.05
16    51.3175 19.5025  5.6950  ... 5.555556  0.76
```

I expected the resulting graph to be colored according to my Biodiv_ factor, but this does not happen.

Comment: I found the solution in using col.ind instead of habillage. Here, I can insert the Biodiv_ parameter as numeric, thus creating the wanted result.

Comment: Can you show the chart?